# How to make WooCommerce coupon code count delivery as an expense

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

We are using WooCommerce coupon codes as gift cards. We understand this is not the original purpose, but we do not have the capacity for anything else at the moment. It is working just fine except one thing: The coupon codes do not count our delivery as an expense. Our delivery is 29. So if the coupon code is worth 300 and they add products for 271 they have to pay the 29 and the other 29 remain on the coupon code.

Is there a simple function or code that'll include the delivery as an expense and minus it from the value of the coupon?

Comment: Coupons discount affect only cart items, but never shipping costs

Comment: Is there a way to change this?

Comment: Maybe but it will be really complicated and very long… So a real development like…